# При передаче в "шаг" цикла результата функции, выдаёт ошибку 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, функции

Решил написать программу, которая сможет просуммировать несколько раз одно и то же число в заданном диапазоне. При этом, что бы шаг цикла составлял дробное число.

```
class calculator:     
                                                                                                                         
    def __init__ (self):                                                                                                                          
        self.y = 0                                                                                                                                
        self.step_c = 1                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                  
    def flt_to_int (self, step_x):                                                                                                                
        while step_x <= 1:                                                                                                                        
            step_x *= 10                                                                                                                          
            self.step_c *= 10                                                                                                                     
        step_x = int (step_x)                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                  
    def add (self, init_x, fin_x, step_x, const):                                                                                                 
        Fout = open ("Initial_File.txt","w")                                                                                                      
        for x in range (init_x, fin_x, step_x):                                                                                                   
            self.y += const                                                                                                                       
            x /= self.step_c                                                                                                                      
            if x == 0:                                                                                                                            
                self.y = 0                                                                                                                        
            Fout.write (f"{x} {self.y}\r\n")                                                                                                      
        Fout.close ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

start = int (input ())                                                                                                                            
finish = int (input ())                                                                                                                           
step = float (input ())                                                                                                                           
const = int (input ())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
calculator().add (start, finish, calculator().flt_to_int(step), const)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: В какой строчке? Нужно копировать весь текст ошибки, а не  половину.

Comment: В строке for x in range (init_x, fin_x, step_x):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не хватает `return step_x` в функции `flt_to_int`

По возможности, наглядное объяснение

```
calculator().add (start, finish, calculator().flt_to_int(step), const)
```

Что вы делаете в этой строчке?

- `calculator()` создаете объект класса calculator
- `.add(...)` вызываете у объекта функцию с четырьмя аргументами

Какие это аргументы?

- `start` - число, которое ввел пользователь, приведенное к `int`
- `finish` - еще одно введеное число
- `calculator().flt_to_int(step)` - а это что такое? Мы к этому вернемся
- `const` - еще одно введенное число

```
calculator().flt_to_int(step)
```

Здесь вы:

- снова создаете объект класса calculator, никак не связанный с объектом, созданным ранее
- вызываете у объекта функцию `flt_to_int` с аргументом `step`

Что делает функция `flt_to_int`?

- принимает аргумент типа `float`
- всячески изменяет его в цикле, финально приводит к `int`
- завершает свою работу
- И все

Что-нибудь смущает?

В Python, если в функции нет явного `return`, то это значит `return None`. А в `add` в качестве третьего аргумента попадает возвращаемое значение `flt_to_int`, а это `None`. И доходя до `range(init_x, fin_x, step_x)` получается `range(init_x, fin_x, None)`, а это ошибка.

Вывод: не хватает `return step_x` в функции `flt_to_int`.

### PS

Пишите полностью все, что выдает интерпретатор, те самые много строк с именами файлов и номерами строк. Это очень важно.

Comment: Cпасибо, помогло. Теперь буду знать как формулировать вопрос.